# why GKLocalPlayer from game center in ios return nill when authenticate succeeded

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I used demo in ios 9 for testing game center, `[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]` returns the right information, but when i used in my app, it returns nil. I cannot find why.The demo and app use the same bundle identifier and signature.

Anyone knows the answer, please help the despairing me!
sorry for poor English, wish you can understand them.
Can it caused by complex thread?
Please answer me!!!!!
Beg your answer!!!!!
SOS!!
[See a code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWpQb.png)

```
//here is some of codes i use;
- (void)authenticateLocalUser : (bool)bLoginGame{

if(!gameCenterAvailable)
{
    return;
}

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO)
{
    [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticateHandler=^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
        if(viewcontroller != nil)
        {
            if(bLoginGame)
            {
                [g_sharedInstanceAppDelegate.viewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
        }
        else if(error == nil && [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated)
        {
            if(bLoginGame)
            {
                NSString* uid = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID;
                NSString* name = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].displayName;
                GameCenterLoginCallback(uid, name, nil, false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"LOGIN FAILED!");
            if(bLoginGame)
            {
                GameCenterLoginCallback(nil, nil, error, true);
            }
        }
    };
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
    if(bLoginGame)
    {
        NSString* uid = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID;
        NSString* name = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].displayName;
        GameCenterLoginCallback([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID, name, nil, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, please click the link for image;

Comment: no! include the code as text, not as image.

Comment: the demo is correct, do you need it? cannot give the app code because it is too large;

Comment: Your code calls `[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]` in multiple places. Which call (or calls) are returning nil?

Comment: please check the link [See a code sample] above， the break point shows where the local player gets the wrong nil value; @Thunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sad for no one give me the right answer...
but today i suddenly found the reason why [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] information is nil.....so i write here, for some one may need it...

> Edit scheme->Run->Diagnostics->unselect [enable address sanitizer].

This will fix the question.But donot know why caused that.